# How to end session in PHP to prevent unallowed access to some directories?

Tags: php, session

I made a search profile of my homepage. When an ordinary user login and change the directory in the web address they can access all the information that should be limited only to a user account.  Example, an ordinary user can access this site:

> http://deped.gov.ph/login/Schools/BacoorES/SearchOutput.php?id=393

But when he change the "BacoorES" into "Admin" it will redirect as an admin user. I need help with how to end the session when the user changes the directory.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['name']){
    }else 
    $home_url='http://www.deped.gov.ph/login';
   header('Location: ' . $home_url);
   ?>

<?php include '../../template-header/header.php' ?>
```

Comment: If the user's name in session doesn't match the directory through a 403 or redirect to the root.

Comment: yes sir what code to add in the if session, BacoorES is a directory sir

Comment: Is `bacoores` an actual directory or is that a GET parameter via htaccess?

Comment: "BacoorES is an actual directory sir

Comment: Do either answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ending the session is how you are going to solve this. One way to do it is to have a session variable with the users access level. So for instance, to begin with it is `0`, when you log in it changes to `1` and if you are an admin it changes to `2`.

Then at the beginning of every page you can check that the user has enough credentials to see them. For instance, for an admin page:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user_level'] < 2) {
    //Redirect to an access denied page.
    header('Location: access_denied.php');
}
else {
    //Here you can put the code for the admin only page.
}
```

Of course there are many, many ways to solve this problem. This is perhaps not the best way in practice, but it illustrates the basic approach. Relying on "security through obscurity", that is asuming people wont figure out the URLs, is not safe, even if you don't do a search profile.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this..

```
$dirpath = '/login/Schools/';
$closing = '/';
if(strpos($dirpath . $_SESSION['name'] . $closing, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) !== FALSE) {
    //user is in correct path
} else {
    //user is guessing throw them out...
}
```

Which will check the currently requested path for the username. The course of action you want to take is up to you.

Note I didn't test the above code as it currently is written because I don't have the directory structure. I tested with.

```
$dirpath = '/testingabc123/';
$closing = ''; //'/';
if(strpos($dirpath . '1246.php' . $closing, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) !== ) {
    echo 'in';
} else {
    echo 'out';
}
```

Where my page was `/testingabc123/1246.php`. The `$closing` is important because without that a username `jon` could match as `jonathon`. Also I presume you don't allow `/`s in your usernames. If you do a user could make their username `/login/Schools/admin/` and this would grant them access..